# Bootstrap Modal zoom out animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to implement a zoom out animation on hide(), [based on the answer](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/267) on the github repo of [bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) (using Bootstrap 2.3.2).

The idea is to add a CSS transition, and intercept the `hide` event, something like:

```
$modal.on('hide', function () {    
    $modal.css({top: 0, left: 0, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)'});
//  return false;    // uncomment this line to see zoom out
});
```

The problem is that the modal is hidden before there's a chance to see the animation.  Returning `false` shows the animation, but keeps the modal box from completing the hiding.

How can I complete the hide process but still see the animation?

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dtyohc28/5/

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little hacky but works. http://jsfiddle.net/dtyohc28/7/

```
$modal.on('hide', function () {    
    $modal.css({top: 0, left: 0, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)'});
    if($modal.css('top')!="0px"){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $modal.modal('hide');
        }, 750);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: it works, so I upvoted it, but I prefer a cleaner solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dtyohc28/6/ Try this, instead of using on('hide'), make your own function to control it.

```
$('#dismissModal').click(function(){
    $modal.css({top: 0, left: 0, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)', opacity:'0'});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.modal').modal('hide')
    },750);
});
```

Comment: I considered that, but it only works when the button is used, not when the backdrop is clicked to dismiss the modal.  I upvoted your answer though.